# (-8)^(-2/3) returns wrong result

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2020b (Mac OS 12.0.1).

When I enter (-8)^(-2/3), it returns:

```
ans =

  -0.1250 - 0.2165i
```

Shouldn't it be 0.2500, instead?

Answer (score 3):

Raising negative numbers to fractional powers is a complex multi-valued operation. MATLAB is simply picking one of the solutions for you. E.g., for the solutions to (-8)^(1/3). start with the roots to the following polynomial equation:

```
x^3+8=0
```

Using MATLAB for this:

```
>> roots([1 0 0 8])
ans =
  -2.0000 + 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 1.7321i
   1.0000 - 1.7321i
```

Then raising this result to the -2 power yields:

```
>> ans.^-2
ans =
   0.2500 + 0.0000i
  -0.1250 - 0.2165i
  -0.1250 + 0.2165i
```

MATLAB happened to give you the second solution above for the (-8)^(-2/3) calculation.

BOTTOM LINE: Whenever you are dealing with complex multi-valued operations, if you want specific results you will need to account for that in your code, because MATLAB might pick something else.

Comment: Matlab did not happened to give that result, instead, it always returns the root of the main branch `(-pi, pi]`, i.e. `(-8)^(-2/3) = 8*exp(pi*(-2/3)) = -0.1250 - 0.2165i`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the order of calculation.

`(-8)^(-2/3)` means divide -2 by 3 and then raise -8 to that power.

But if you do `((-8)^(-2))^(1/3)` or `nthroot((-8)^(-2),3)` instead, you'll get 0.25.